# Using libipt, how does one add a matching rule such as 'dport' for TCP packets?

Tags: c++, c, netfilter

I've been trying to add netfilter rules programmatically without making calls to the iptables binary. Aside from the header files for libipt, the closest thing to documentation I've found is [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Querying-libiptc-HOWTO/index.html). There's nothing in the documentation describing what I want to do, oddly enough.

In ip_tables.h at the bottom of the `ipt_entry` struct is the following bit of code:

```
/* The matches (if any), then the target. */
    unsigned char elems[0];
```

However, I haven't found any way to properly read or modify `elems`.

I also tried adding a rule via iptables `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dest 192.168.1.10 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT` and then running a program that calls into libipt like so: `ipt_entry *rule = iptc_first_rule(chain, iptHandle);`. I ran it in GDB and broke on the line following
`iptc_first_rule`. Dumping the ipt_entry structure gives me this:

```
(gdb) p *rule
$4 = {
  ip = {
    src = {
      s_addr = 0
    }, 
    dst = {
      s_addr = 167880896
    }, 
    smsk = {
      s_addr = 0
    }, 
    dmsk = {
      s_addr = 4294967295
    }, 
    iniface = '\000' <repeats 15 times>, 
    outiface = '\000' <repeats 15 times>, 
    iniface_mask = '\000' <repeats 15 times>, 
    outiface_mask = '\000' <repeats 15 times>, 
    proto = 6, 
    flags = 0 '\000', 
    invflags = 0 '\000'
  }, 
  nfcache = 0, 
  target_offset = 160, 
  next_offset = 200, 
  comefrom = 2, 
  counters = {
    pcnt = 0, 
    bcnt = 0
  }, 
  elems = 0x77e85b58 "0"
}
```

I saw that there was *something* in the `elems` member, so I tried dumping it too:

```
(gdb) x /10s rule->elems
0x77e85b58:     "0"
0x77e85b5a:     "tcp"
0x77e85b5e:     "%s"
0x77e85b61:     ""
0x77e85b62:     ""
0x77e85b63:     ""
0x77e85b64:     "%s(): set IP_HDRINC"
0x77e85b78:     ""
0x77e85b79:     ""
0x77e85b7a:     "\377\377P"
```

Lastly, I tried looking at the source code of iptables. However, I had to stop looking at that spaghetti soup before throwing myself out of the nearest window.

How in the heck do you specify a destination port for a rule?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, the target platform is openWRT, which doesn't provide any of the newer netfilter libraries. I'm stuck with libipt/xtables.

Comment: elems is a "flexible array member"

Comment: @user253751 I suppose you mean that 'elems' is allowed to vary in size? I am aware of that, but I'm not sure how to use 'elems' to achieve what I want to do.

Comment: I think you are supposed to put some `struct iptc_entry_match`s and then a `struct iptc_entry_target` after the `struct iptc_entry` in memory